# Title not displaying correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have set up a title instance variable in application_helper.rb, but the base_title does not display  in the browser. Can you tell me what's wrong?

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Return a title on a per-page basis
  def title
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if @title.nil?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= @title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        </head>
        <body>
            <%= yield %>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view you're not actually calling the helper function, it's just trying to output the instance variable (@title), don't prefix a function call with @:

```
<title><%= title %></title>
```